# Можно ли как-то передавать данные в отображаемый компонент в router-outlet?

Tags: angular

Допустим, есть компонент в котором присутствует router-outlet и хотелось бы в `@Input()` отображаемого компонента что-то передать, что бы инициализировать его. Например, пробрасывать аргументы из роута.

Каким образом можно реализовать задуманное?

Видел решение через "расшаренные сервисы", но в этом случае мой компонент будет иметь лишнюю зависимость, в то время как инициализация через @Input'ы более гибкая.

**UPD**

Есть еще мысль создать узкоспециализированный компонент-контейнер, который будет заниматься маршлингом данных в дочерней компонент. Тогда в него можно внедрить сервис и в тоже время не трогать основной компонент оставляя его гибким. Правильный ли это путь?

Comment: нет, нельзя. И зачем? :) для этого есть резолверы

Comment: Ну, допустим, данные нужные для работы компонента лежат в параметрах маршрута. Мне не хочется, что бы сам компонент за ними лез, а хочу, что бы ему их пробрасывали в @Input'ы, как мне кажется- это правильнее, так как в таком случае я могу его внедрить куда захочу.

Comment: не мыслите паттернами из других языков программирования, в angular есть все необходимое из ядра (скажу вам по секрету) :D

Comment: @overthesanity, в таком случае жду вашего ответа=) Как пробросить в компонент параметры маршрута, но в тоже время не сузить область применения компонента(Что бы в него можно было явно запихнуть аргументы и т д.). Имхо, наверное, то что я описал в UPD верный путь.

Comment: iluxa, почитайте про резолверы (это концепция дата провайдеров), то есть логика получение данных изолируется и компонент уже получает готовый чанк "чего угодно". сначала почитайте и отпишитесь по прогрессу, дам ответ когда у вас будет что-то не получаться

Comment: @overthesanity а маст хев статью не подкините, желательно на русском?

Comment: компонент контейнер не нужен, все компоненты отвечают только за представление и в принципе им должно быть плевать на хттп запросы и прочую ерунду, `@Input` нужны в случаях когда вы явно указываете компонент в шаблоне, а в роутинге - это динамический компонент, который проджектит директива router-outlet через ComponentFactoryResolver, поэтому с инпутами тут не прокатит

Comment: на русском увы нету, есть только на англ - [вот раз](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/), [вот два](https://codeburst.io/understanding-resolvers-in-angular-736e9db71267), но это не сложно

Comment: @overthesanity прикольная штука. Но все равно, мне кажется, что с Input'ами более гибко. Допустим у меня есть 10-ок компонентов, которые инициализируются через Input'ы. Я их все могу собрать в одном контейнере, а контейнер сам им все пробросит данные.

Comment: это не гибко потому что с инпутами получается большой поток данных сверху вниз (если очень много компонентов), по нормальному всегда есть роутинговый компонент, он получил данные через резолвер, а дальше раскидал эти данные через инпуты по дочерним компонентам

Comment: все реюзабл компоненты зависят только от входных параметров, но это не гибкость, это юзабилити, какой-то компонент `app-button` не должен отвечать за посыл реквеста на сервер при клике на кнопку, он должен генерировать событие, а за реквест уже отвечает родительский компонент, который нельзя реюзать, их еще называют presentational

Comment: @overthesanity, по идее, в своем UPD я что-то вроде этого и имел ввиду. Т.е контейнер, который содержит в себе элементы, разжевывает данные из роутов и инициализирует компоненты.

Comment: @overthesanity,А что вы подразумеваете под 'роутинговый компонент'? Тот который имеет в себе router-outlet или представление, которое отображается в router-outlet? Если первое, то немного не понимаю, как раскидать разресолвенные данные в то, что отображается в данный момент в router-outlet.

Comment: `{ path: 'blah', component: RoutingComponent <-- }`

Answer (score 1):

Обещают в 8й версии запилить такое https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18967#issuecomment-454598521

Компонент-контейнер - вполне норм идея. Да и в принципе, иметь компоненты-контейнеры специально для отображения страниц - вполне ок. В этом популярном репо с примером прилажения именно так и делают https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app/blob/master/src/app/modules/heroes/heroes-routing.module.ts